# Handle event from another class (java)

Tags: java, swing, events

i'm at a standstill developing a java application.
I have a series of JFrames that open each other, and once I open the next, the frame before shall close.
Now, all works fine, I used

```
setVisible(false);
```

to "close" the frame, but I have some problems with a specific form I generated:
The form has some panels inside, and the panels each have a button which opens the next form. Now, I wonder how can I apply `setVisible(false)` to the form that contains those panels.

*ChooseForm* is the name of the form that contains the panels;
And I have this event handling the button click of each panel's button

```
private void btn_scegliMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    Database.getAbitazioneByCodice(label_codice.getText());
    MainForm.showFrame();

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You may use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component)

Comment: *"I have a series of JFrames .."* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.
A Simple way you can do like this:

```
class YourFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private YourPanel panel;

    public YourFrame() {
        //...
        panel.addButtonActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //show other Frame and hide this Frame
    }
}
class YourPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton yourButton;

    public void addButtonActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        yourButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```